# How to successfully change Postgresql data folder

Tags: postgresql

enter code hereI followed the instructions [here](https://fitodic.github.io/how-to-change-postgresql-data-directory-on-linux) and although it seems successful and Postgres starts up I get the following error:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any help to figure this out.

[image: successful start of postgresql]

below is the output of /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log

```
    pg_ctl: directory "/mnt/postgres_data" is not a database cluster directory
2022-02-05 17:15:54.321 UTC [9484] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0>
2022-02-05 17:15:54.322 UTC [9484] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2022-02-05 17:15:54.341 UTC [9484] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-02-05 17:15:54.380 UTC [9485] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-02-05 17:04:32 UTC
2022-02-05 17:15:54.393 UTC [9484] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-02-05 17:29:39.339 UTC [9484] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2022-02-05 17:29:39.340 UTC [9484] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-02-05 17:29:39.347 UTC [9484] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 9491) exited with exit code 1
2022-02-05 17:29:39.352 UTC [9486] LOG:  shutting down
2022-02-05 17:29:39.372 UTC [9484] LOG:  database system is shut down
2022-02-05 19:44:20.272 UTC [1236] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0>
2022-02-05 19:44:20.285 UTC [1236] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2022-02-05 19:44:20.287 UTC [1236] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-02-05 19:44:20.376 UTC [1237] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-02-05 17:29:39 UTC
2022-02-05 19:44:20.447 UTC [1236] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-02-05 19:47:33.160 UTC [1236] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2022-02-05 19:47:33.163 UTC [1236] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 1243) exited with exit code 1
2022-02-05 19:47:33.165 UTC [1238] LOG:  shutting down
2022-02-05 19:47:33.213 UTC [1236] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

The only line I changed in postgresql.conf is the one below.  The 'mnt/postgres_data/main' folder is on a Truenas server.  The permissions are below too.

```
bigdaddy@weatherserver:/etc/postgresql/12/main$ ls -al /mnt
total 82
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096 Feb  4 19:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root     root     4096 Feb  4 19:09 ..
drwxrwxr-x  7 media    media      38 Jan 29 14:28 Documents
drwx------  3 postgres postgres    4 Feb  5 19:54 postgres_data

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FILE LOCATIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
# option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

#data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/12/main'         # use data in another directory
data_directory = '/mnt/postgres_data/main'
```

Comment: That's not a successful server start. What parts of the instructions did you follow that were 'successful' ?

Comment: All of the instructions seemed successful.  I have experimented quite a bit and the only thing that makes this error happen is changing the data_directory flag in postgresql.conf.  When I change it back to the default of /var/lib/postgresql/12/main.  The new data directory has the exact same permissions as the /main directory.

Comment: Why do you think the server has started successfully? Could you show us the postgreSQL logfiles, and especially the lines that shows that the server has started?

Comment: I added more information to the post.  Thanks.

Comment: Please post those logs and error messages as text, not as paintings of text.

Comment: Are you able to initialise a new db with this as the data directory. Then use pg_dump and restore to effectively move your database. ?

Comment: The existing database is blank.  I don't have anything to move.  As far as a new db I don't know how to do that.  I will begin searching.  Thanks.

Comment: `initdb -D [target database directory] start`

Answer (score 0):

When you initially install postgres on Ubuntu it starts a cluster that it calls main.  It is essentially a default cluster.  It has a fixed directory of
`/var/lib/postgresql/12/main` and `/etc/postgresql/12/main`
The 12 is the version number for postgres.  The default location for the postgresql.conf files are in the folder of the instance under the following.
`/etc/postgresql/12/….`.
It is here that you set the behaviour of each instance.  I wanted to add a storage location that was on the Truenas server.  To do this required the following command as the postgres user.

```
pg_createcluster –datadir=/mnt/postgres_data 12 <instance name>
```

Again the 12 represents the version of postgres you have installed.  You can have several versions of postgres and do this for all of those different versions.
There are a bunch of other pg_ commands that you can use too.

```
pg_lsclusters – lists the clusters that are installed and whether they are active or not.
```

You can start and stop individual clusters with the following command

```
 systemctl stop postgresql@12-main
```

Where the 12 is again the postgresql version number and main the name of the cluster.  Main is the name of the default cluster created.
Everything I found on line indicated that I could move the contents of the main cluster to the new storage location.  That didn’t work.  I think now the reason it didn’t was because there are 2 folders.
/var/lib/postgresql/12/main and /etc/postgresql/12/main
The video below got me going in the right direction.
Be sure to note that the new clusters are assigned a different port number.  This is what is used to connect to the cluster over the same IP address.
pg_lsclusters lists the port number for each cluster.  By default each successive cluster is given the next port, i.e. 5432+1 for the next cluster.

[Managing the instance/cluster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZCCKBBwbzY)

[Ubuntu manpage pg_createcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html)